# bad access code 1 using realm when comparing rlmobject to nil

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

I have a syncing engine with a server that follows this code for created updated and deleted objects

```
let lastSynchronizationDate = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("com.fridge.sync") as [String: NSDate])["skin"]!
    query.whereKey("updatedAt", greaterThanOrEqualTo: lastSynchronizationDate)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (remoteSkins, error) -> Void in
      if error != nil {
        return
      }
      if remoteSkins.isEmpty {
        return
      }
      RLMRealm.defaultRealm().transactionWithBlock {
        let deletedSkins = (remoteSkins as [PFObject]).filter {
          $0["state"] as Int == 0
          }.map {
            Skin(forPrimaryKey: $0["color"])
          }.filter {
            $0 != nil
          }.map {
            $0!
        }
        let createdSkins = (remoteSkins as [PFObject]).filter {
          $0["state"] as Int != 0
          }.filter {
            let skin = Skin(forPrimaryKey: $0["color"])
            println(skin.name)
            return skin == nil
          }.map { (remoteSkin) -> Skin in
            let remoteSkinModel = RemoteSkinModel(remoteSkin)
            let skin = Skin()
            skin.skinModel = remoteSkinModel // Error
            return skin
        }
        let updatedSkins = (remoteSkins as [PFObject]).filter {
          $0["state"] as Int != 0
          }.map {
            ($0, Skin(forPrimaryKey: $0["color"]))
          }.filter {
            $0.1 != nil
          }.map {
            $0.1.skinModel = RemoteSkinModel($0.0)
        }
        RLMRealm.defaultRealm().deleteObjects(deletedSkins)
        RLMRealm.defaultRealm().addObjects(createdSkins)
      }
    }
```

My skin model:

```
class Skin: RLMObject {
  dynamic var name: String = ""
  dynamic var hexString: String = ""

  var skinModel: SkinModel! {
    didSet {
      name = skinModel.name ?? oldValue.name ?? ""
      hexString = skinModel.hexString ?? oldValue.name ?? ""
    }
  }

  override class func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "hexString"
  }

  override class func ignoredProperties() -> [AnyObject] {
    return ["skinModel"]
  }

  func save() {

  }
}

protocol SkinModel {
  var name: String { get }
  var hexString: String { get }
}

class RemoteSkinModel: SkinModel {
  let remoteSkin: PFObject
  let name: String
  let hexString: String

  init(_ remoteSkin: PFObject) {
    self.remoteSkin = remoteSkin
    self.name = remoteSkin["name"] as? String ?? ""
    self.hexString = remoteSkin["color"] as? String ?? ""
  }
}
```

The first the engine runs everything goes well, but the next time it pops the bad access error when comparing if the realm object is nil or not in the createdSkins' code.
Any idea as to why this would happen?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you force `skin` to be an optional?

```
let skin: Sin? = Skin(forPrimaryKey: $0["color"])
if let skin = skin {
    println(skin.name)
}
return skin == nil
```

I think the Swift compiler may be preventing checks to nil because `Skin(forPrimaryKey:)` should be a failable initializer, but Realm can't mark that as such (only Apple code can have those).

If that's not the issue, let me know and we'll keep troubleshooting this together. (I work at Realm).